# Mac os x JMenuItem accelerator not displaying

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenuitem, jmenubar

After setting up a JMenuBar and adding it to a JFrame, I have the normal menu (in the top of the JFrame) and the keyboard shortcuts (accelerators) are nicely displayed next to each JMenuItem (Thus the JMenuBar is working correctly). The problem however is that after using the following lines of code to show the JMenuItem in top of the screen, the shortcuts wont be displayed next to the JMenuItems anymore.

```
if((System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X"))) {
    System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
}
```

Even stranger is that the shortcuts do get displayed for the JCheckBoxMenuItems.
Does anyone know how this is possible?

Possible useful information:

- Software:  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5
- Java: Version 7 Update 9, JDK 1.9

FurtherMore, It is still not entirely clear to me what the mnemonic keys do. Does a the mnemonic key of a JMenuItem add any functionality if the JMenuItem alrady has a accelerator?

If there are any question, dont hesitate to ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: mnemonic's are used to navigate in menus when they are visible and have the focus, and possibly fire the action of the menu. Shortcuts/Accelerators are used to directly fire the action of the menu with a given KeyStroke and most of the time the menu is not even visible

Comment: Alright, but do u have any idea why the accelerators do not show up in the JMenuBar?

Comment: Nope, no idea. All I know is that Java support on MacOS has been lame for years. Hopefully the situation will improve with OpenJDK.

Comment: Are you sure your problem only occurs on MacOS? If not, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and we will have a look into it.

Comment: @Triplle Did you find a solution to your problem? I have the same problem of the accelerator keys not showing up and the actions activated twice when the combination of keys is pressed.

Comment: @Igor: Action activated twice was a bug, Oracle has fixed that in the latest release. Accelerators not displaying is most likely a bug as well; possibly one for that a work-a-round may exit, but it is a bug nonetheless. Unless someone here reports this bug to Oracle (as they are now making the JVMs for OSX), this bug will probably not get fixed I'd say.

Comment: @Mecki Actually, it was fixed in JDK 1.7 :)

Comment: @Igor: I have 1.7.0_09 installed and on my system they are still not displayed albeit working. Currently updating to 1.7.0_21 to see if the issue was really fixed.